# Laravel how to access images from another folder within the view

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm having problems accessing images that I use for my google maps markers within the view.

I start php artisan serve and get value of img location from database.
But when I print img, I can't reach the location (NotFoundHttpException), for example (storage/app/public/img/markers/stan.png).

Where should I put img folder and how to access it with "var image" from my view?

Comment: Which laravel version are we talking of btw?

Comment: 5.2, btw why does that matters?

Answer (score 0):

Only the `/public` folder in the root of your app is accessible by default.  You can put images in `/public/img` and the url will be `yourdomain.com/img/markers/stan.png`

Comment: Ok. I set img folder inside public folder. 
Tried this inside my content div in 

'recources/views/welcome.blade.php'

'<div class="panel-body">
       <img src="public/img/markers/stan.png">
       <img src="img/markers/bolnica.png">
</div>'

and still I don't get either of my images displayed. 

If I click right click on image and go to 

'mydomain.com/img/markers/stan.png'

I still get error 404 not found

The requested resource /img/markers/stan.png was not found on this server.

:/

Comment: and your file is in `mylaravelapp/public/img/markers/stan.png`? That would be an odd 404... did you sync the files up to your server after moving them?

Comment: I'm using localhost, localdatabase if that's what are you asking? :/ I'm not exactly sure what are you asking with "sync" ... I'm new to laravel but I'm very confused because that. I'm working whole day on this and still can't get it right.

Comment: is your app served at `localhost:8000` or `localhost:8000/public`?

Comment: I imagine you have your css and js in the public folder as well?  your images would be in the public folder just the same.  I am not sure I can help if you have them in `mylaravelapp/public/img/markers/stan.png` they should be live at `localhost:8000/img/markets/stan.png`.  The only option beyond that is your `.htaccess` file might be incorrect, are you using the `.htaccess` file as-is from laravel? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: It's a new project, I don't have any css except layout>app.blade.php inside resources folder. I only have route to ('/') and resources>views>welcome.blade.php where I'm trying to display my images

Answer (score 0):

If you definitely need to have these files inside `storage`, you could `symlink` the path `storage/app/public/img/markers` to `public/img/markers`.